# Does anyone have a working example for the new Next JS app folder Layouts RFC?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Read this post about a new way of structuring pages in-app folder in Next JS, but I can't find any example.

[Layout RFC Blogpost](https://nextjs.org/blog/layouts-rfc)

Is this not yet available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>Found the answer on GitHub. It's just a proposal.</s>

Edit: since Next 13, this feature is live

next ripo

https://github.com/vercel/next.js